# C++ preprocessor __typeof

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Recently I have found and I have started using in my preprocessor the following code:

```
#define FOREACH(i,s) for(VAR(i,(s).begin()); i != (s).end(); i++)
#define VAR(a,b) __typeof(b) a=(b)
```

what makes my iterating easier. But unfortunately I don't fully understand the second line, especially the `__typeof` keyword (and why those two underscores are used). I also assumed that the whole expression `__typeof(b)` is a type casting, but when I take it in parenthesis, why it does not work?

Comment: "recently I have found and I have started using in my preprocessor the following code"  Now would be a good time to stop.  Obfuscating control statements using macros is a very bad idea.

Comment: Good answers been given, I'd like to add, that you shouldn't use all that stuff now, with c++11, when you can use range-based-for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for-loop

Comment: Indeed, this range_based-for (similar to Java) will solve the problem. I know that for others such code is not clear, but it help me to keep my code more transparent(of course I use such macros only when I write programs for my own usage)

Comment: Then you may be interested in how it is made in Qt: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/master/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h#line2333 Allows to write code `foreach(int i, vector_of_ints) {cout << i;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assume some real values for i and s to see what it does:

```
std::list<int> list;
FOREACH(i, list)
```

This will resolve in the macro `FOREACH(i, list)`:

```
for(VAR(i, (list).begin()); i != (list).end(); i++)
```

Now resolve macro `VAR(i, (list).begin())`:

```
__typeof((list).begin()) i = (list).begin();
```

Where __typeof gets the type of the Argument `(list).begin()` which is in this case `std::list<int>::iterator`

```
std::list<int>::iterator i = (list).begin();
```

Now insert this into the for and get:

```
for(std:list<int>::iterator i = (list).begin(); i != (list).end(); i++)
```

As you see the __typeof part is no typecast but a declaration, so the paranthesis are wrong there.

Also note the many comments on why not to use macros and __typeof in special!

Answer (score 4):

`__typeof(b)` is not a cast. It is non-standard C++ usable with G++, and means "the type of b". In other words, it's a type, and `__typeof(b) a=(b);` is a definition which defines `a` as having the same type as `b`, and is initialised from `b`. So after `int b = 3;`, it means `int a = b;`.

Standard C++11 (which is fairly new and not yet fully implemented by any compiler that I know of) includes a mostly similar feature called `decltype`.

Comment: And apart from that, almost every use of `decltype` can be replaced by `auto` (especially the one given). Both are fully implemented in g++ at least since 4.5.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about that. Thanks.

Comment: @filmor: only when used as type specifier for local variables. There are lots of uses for decltype in metaprogramming which can't be replaced with auto